# PopupWindow overlaps soft buttons on Android 5.0

Tags: android

I have a simple `PopupWindow` that I create with the following code (the code is in C#, the Java code should be basically the same)

```
View popupView = LayoutInflater.From(this.Activity).Inflate(Resource.Layout.LectionFooter, null);

var popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, false)
{
    OutsideTouchable = true,
    AnimationStyle = Resource.Style.FooterAnimation
};

popup.SetBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
popup.ShowAtLocation(rootView, GravityFlags.Bottom, 0, 0);
```

On pre-Lollipop devices, this popup looks fine, but on Android 5.0, the popup overlaps the soft buttons:

[image: PopupWindow Lollipop]

Here's the `PopupWindow` on an Android 4.4 device:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is possible bug in android api 21 that's why they introduced [popup.setAttachedInDecor(true/false);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setAttachedInDecor%28boolean%29) method in api 22
however there is a workout, you can set right `y` coordinate for your popup as follows:

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
int winHeight = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
popup.showAtLocation(rootView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, winHeight-rect.bottom);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I can award you the bounty in 14 hours, write a comment in case I forget it

Comment: This issue exists for Dialogs with BOTTOM gravity too.  This solution seems to work the same in calculating the y offset.